# Join multiple arrays by their index

Tags: php

I got arrays like these:

```
{
[0] => "Alex"
[1] => "Carlos"
[2] => "Juan"
...
}

{
[0] => "Present"
[1] => "Present"
[2] => "Absent"
...
}

{
[0] => "1"
[1] => "0"
[2] => "1"
...
}

{
[0] => "red"
[1] => "blue"
[2] => "green"
...
}
```

Each array is generated dynamically from a form and they all have the same length. I would to have them sorted or combined by their index, like this:

```
{"Alex", "Present", "1", "red"}
{"Carlos", "Present", "0", "blue"}
{"Juan", "Absent", "1", "green"}
...
```

My plan is to save each sorted list in a database, I already have all the code for it, except for the sorting, I'm kind of lost, I wasn't able to find anything related. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: how  this is related to mysql ??????

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below it will work, but out there a better solution exist.

```
<?php
$ar = [
    [
        "Alex",
        "Carlos",
        "Juan",
    ], [
        "Present",
        "Present",
        "Absent",
    ], [
        "red",
        "blue",
        "green",
    ],
];

$arNew = [];
foreach ($ar as $i => $ar1) {
    foreach ($ar1 as $j => $item) {
        $arNew[$j][$i] = $item;
    }
}

print_r($arNew);
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Alex
            [1] => Present
            [2] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Carlos
            [1] => Present
            [2] => blue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Juan
            [1] => Absent
            [2] => green
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
<?php
$mulArray = [
    ["Alex", "Carlos", "Juan"],
    ["Present", "Present", "Absent"],
    ["1", "0", "1",],
    ["red", "blue", "green"],
];

$result = [];
$elementCount = count($mulArray);
// Iterate through all sub array
for($i=0; $i < ($elementCount-1); $i++){
    // Iterate through all index of sub array
    for($z=0; $z <= ($elementCount-1); $z++){
        $result[$i][] = $mulArray[$z][$i];
    }    
}
    
print_r($result);
```